# Set ID on creation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm actually starting a new project with elasticsearch, I never used this so I do a lot of research and I just need 1 answer :

How can I choose the ID of an object when I create it ?
For example, when I create this object :

```
{
  "title": "Facebook API Data PHP", 
   "category": "PHP",
   "tags": [
      "Facebook",
      "API"
   ],
   "test2": 3.5252156144514514521  
}
```

The ID by default is something like this : `AVxYqhmCnGpDth4S4vBA`
And I want to set the ID when I create the object to something like that `object_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ID while indexing the data into Elasticsearch. Like

```
PUT indexName/typeName/object_1
{
  "title": "Facebook API Data PHP", 
   "category": "PHP",
   "tags": [
      "Facebook",
      "API"
   ],
   "test2": 3.5252156144514514521  
}
```